# knockout image src hangs page

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a page that loads about 2 dozen images.  I'm using knockout to compute the url for them at load time (they're actually created by a controller on the backend).  The requests all end up firing at once, which is fine, except the page hangs until the requests return and the images are loaded into the page.

The code I'm using is this, in the ko Model:

```
    self.imageSrc = ko.observable(self.imageUrl(self.id(), self.x(), self.y()));
```

and on the html side:

```
    <img data-bind="attr: {src: imageSrc}"/>
```

I've tried loading the images into a javascript `new Image()` and then putting them into the page later, but the same thing happens.

Any thoughts on how I can keep my page responsive while the images fetch, and then cram them in after they load?

(Using Chrome, btw)

Comment: could you offload your image loading to a web worker?  http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/using-web-workers-to-speed-up-your-javascript-applications

Comment: I have no idea.  I'll have to read about web workers.  :)